# Changing a style element when a Class is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have an element without an ID using class name "optin-box" and I have a nav item with a class of "my-nav" which currently has margin-top:46px. When I click on the optin box, I want to remove the margin-top from the "my-nav" class

Closest I have got is this:

```
 $(".optin-box").on('click', (function(event) {
    $(".my-nav").removeAttr("style");
    console.log('firing');
});
```

Or this

```
$(".optin-box").click (function() {
    $(".my-nav").css('margin-top', '0 !important');
    console.log('firing');
});
```

And tried variations but I cant get it to work. The console log outputs but the nav does move at all.

Comment: It would help to see your actual HTML and CSS here. How is the `margin-top` applied to the element? Via `style` or a CSS class?

Comment: you can make another class and use `.removeClass('existing class_name')` then `addClass('new_class')`

Comment: It does not matter whether its been applied via css or style. Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prwrp3xk/), Its working fine. I'm afraid that you are accessing the wrong element

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Try the following:

```
$(".optin-box").on('click', (function(event) {
    $(".my-nav").css("margin-top", ""); //Thi will remove margin-top from your style tag
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a value to that style, which you want to chsnge.

```
$('my-nav').css ('margin-top': 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , it will reset margin to 0px.

```
$('.my-nav').css('margin-top', '');
```

Example:

```
 <p id="change" style="margin-top:20px"> Let me check </p>
  <input type="button" value="ChangeMargin" id="btn"> 

 $('#btn').click(function () 
 { // alert('btn') 
   $('#change').css('margin-top', ''); })
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close `(function(){})`, added `)` to the end of function.

```js
$(".optin-box").on('click', (function(event) {
   $(".my-nav").removeAttr("style");
   console.log('firing');
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="my-nav" style="margin-top:50px;">my-nav</div>
<button type="button" class="optin-box">optin-box</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abc").click(function(){
       $(".my-nav").css("margin-top", "0px");
    });
});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  margin-top : 50px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="my-nav">

  <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>

  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>

</div>
<p class="abc">Click here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better is to have a class which defines the margin

```
.mt {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Use addClass/removeClass to toggle the mt

```
$(".my-nav").removeClass("mt");
```